# rsync filling destination, --delete-before not working

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

I've had a rsync task doing my backups for some time, copying data from my FreeNAS system to a raspberry pi (w/ external disk). The source size data directory is 2tb and the total size of the remote disk is 4tb. The rsync I've used for this backup is below.

```
rsync --partial --stats -e ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa --progress --delete -ratp -e ssh -p 22 -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes /mnt/storage/docs colo_backup@10.0.60.10:/media/backup/sda1
```

I recently deleted the source on freenas at `/mnt/storage/docs` and restored it to `/mnt/storage/files`. Lots of the permissions changed. Not concerned with the permissions I updated my rsync command as shown below (removing `-p` and for no good reason added `--chmod=ug+rwx`).

```
rsync --partial --stats -e ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa --progress --chmod=ug+rwx --delete -rat -e ssh -p 22 -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes /mnt/storage/files colo_backup@10.0.60.10:/media/backup/sda1
```

The copy at this point is failing as the remote 4tb disk is filling up. Thinking it's trying to copy over a full new set (now that I've messed with permissions) I tried using `--delete-before` thinking it would delete out-of-sync files prior to copying over new. But still, it's filling the disk. I'm running rsync 3.1.3. Not sure where to go from here. Appreciate the help, thanks!

Comment: The first question is: if the destination disk is full up, have you explored its content? Can you see files that you are not expecting to be there?

Comment: @PierU Simply comparing the roots they're the same. In an attempt to compare sizes, on the remote, I did a quick `du -h --max-depth=1 /media/backup/sda1/` and totaled all the directories larger than 1024MB (excluding 30 directories that were less than 1gb). The total came to 1.9tb (add back the 30 less than 1gb directories and I'm back at my 2tb. No idea what is utilizing the other space on the 4TB drive.

Comment: Oh wait... I see it now...  Looks like at some point I must have goofed a trailing `/` in my remote path. Long story short, I have the following directory `/media/backup/sda1/files` on the remote. That said, I have all my backups in `/media/backup/sda1` and an entire duplicate of them in `/media/backup/sda1/files`. Thanks, @PierU for asking the obvious "Can you see files that you are not expecting to be there?".

Comment: So to be clear, when my rsync job was originally created it was setup like this `rsync {args removed} /mnt/storage/docs/ /media/backup/sda1`. When I updated it with the new source path I accidentally omitted the trailing `/` on the source as shown here `rsync {args removed} /mnt/storage/files /media/backup/sda1`. This resulted in creating a directory `files` on the remote. The prior backup was one directory up in `/media/backup/sda1`.

Comment: I was indeed suspecting something like that, as this is a classical source of error with `rsync` (each time I set up a new rsync command I have to think twice where to put the `/ `!).